# Tablespaces in Oracle

Tags: performance, oracle, oracle9i

Is adding tablespaces to a database decrease the performance of an Oracle 9 database?
We consider that the number of request remains constant.

Thx,

Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, tablespaces allow you to logically separate objects, and adding more makes no difference - you have the same amount of data stored on the same amount of disk.

How tables and indexes are organised across tablespaces can make a difference; particularly having indexes in different tablespaces to their tables, though that's really to do with the underlying data files and how those are organised on disk. (I think there's some debate about whether even that makes much difference any more, as disk technology has improved, and with the widespread use of SAN/NAS.)

Comment: +1 - probably more of a consideration these days for separate tablespaces has to do with application maintenance, e.g. partitioning applications to take advantage of transportable tablespaces, moving historical data to read-only tablespaces, etc.