# How to grant user access to additional tablespaces in Oracle?

Tags: oracle10g, sql-grant, tablespace

I want to know How to grant user access to additional tablespaces in Oracle? , because I have created two additional tablespaces, one for data and the other for indexes, like this discussion said:

[Tablespaces in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531931/tablespaces-in-oracle)

I’m doing it for performance.

Comment: The answer you referenced said that tablespaces will not help performance. (Did you read it?) This is true today because "everyone" is using RAID disks. The "separate disk" approach was popular when everyone was using "just a bunch of SCSI disks."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old way was to `grant quota on tablespacename to username`,  which allowed users to create objects on that tablespace. You can still do it that way, but there is a more current method (which I cannot recall at the moment).